# Internet Explorer with Google Chrome Frame - Resources from Amazon CloudFront hang for 2 minutes

Tags: http-request, connection-timeout, google-chrome-frame

CSS and JS resources for my site is hosted on Amazon's CloudFront CDN. The site itself and it's resources are accessed through HTTPS.

When browsing the site in Internet Explorer 8 with Google's Chrome Frame plug-in installed, the site takes exactly two minutes to load.

This happens when refreshing the page (by pressing F5 or by clicking the refresh button). **But if I navigate to the site "manually"** by typing in the URL in the address-bar, or simply highlighting the URL and pressing ENTER, the page loads instantly -- I suspect that this just causes a re-render of the page, and does not trigger a reload as such.

The network-inspector bundled with Google Chrome Frame shows most resources as being not modified (304), but other resources, at random - *which I know are not modified, and should be cached* - are pending for 2 minutes, and then resolving to a 304.

I suspect that the 2 minuts is Google Chrome Frame's internal timeout limit, and when it reaches that limit, it simply discards the resource and loads from cache.

Here are some screenshots from the network inspector: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMVQR.jpg

1. Initial load, highlighted resource takes 2 minutes to resolve.
2. Headers of the request. There is nothing in the response-tab yet, because the resource hasn't loaded, and is pending.
3. After 2 minutes the request resolves to a 304 not modified.
4. End-state of the page-load.

What is wrong here? I am completely clueless.

I should note, that when I disable caching, everything runs smoothly - except of course besides the fact that the browser loads all resources, at every request to the site, which is not a viable solution.

Comment: My company is currently experiencing the same issue - I know it's a long shot, but did you ever resolve this?