# Google Chrome Frame and Amazon Cloud Front CDN Timeout?

Tags: javascript, httprequest, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, google-chrome-frame

Our company is currently experiencing an issue with Google Chrome Frame enabled browsers and a third party site that utilizes an Amazon CloudFront CDN. For all CSS and JS files on the CDN, chrome sits on a request for 2 minutes exactly, and then returns with a 304 and loads the page.

We need chrome frame active, and it doesn't look like we can disable it for specific sites if the site is sending down the chrome frame headers.

Has anyone experienced this before? Is there any way to force the timeout to occur quicker. Why would that be happening in the first place?

Duplicate dead question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160583/internet-explorer-with-google-chrome-frame-resources-from-amazon-cloudfront-ha).